# What exactly is going on when form_for is called in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

If this code is embedded into an html document and that html document is requested, is `form_for` only called once to return the form in HTML for that page?

Most importantly, What is being passed in for `f` in the block? What is the purpose of it?

edit: also, what is responsible for passing in `f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you are a little new to the magic of rails, so i understand your question.

Form_For does many things, at it's most basic level it generates the proper html for RESTful interaction with your web server.  Where it goes a step further is it determines if @user is a new model or one that already exists.  If it is a new model, it sends the request to your new action as a post.  If @user already exists in your database it sets up all the right things for your webpage to do an update on the record.

To get a better grasp I recommend checking out codeschool.com rails for zombies, it will probably help you alot.  Or read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

|f| is a ruby block and it yeilds a form builder object (which is f) and then the methods like .lable, or .submit are called on that form builder object.

The form builder object is aware of your @user because you pass it in, so it is able to make intelligent decisions about whether it is a new model or a current model because of that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I definitely did need to know that `f` is a form builder object, thank you for that. But do you also know what class or object is responsible for passing `f` into that block when it is run?

Comment: Hey Byron, the form_for is a rails method that is provided by the ActionView::Helpers module.  In the context of rails though the class is irrelevant to most developers.  The way I look at it, Rails provides modules that make my life easier so I use them.  When i need to do something different that what is provided out of the box (which is actually quite rare) I extend something or build my own items.  Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

the f variable is used to called helper methods like label,textfield and submit buttons for that form.please see the generated  html source in browser.

Answer (score 0):

In block of form `|f|` is a form builder object. So you don't need to write again and again form_for. It is called for method like textfield, radio button, label, submit button for that form. You can replace **f** with any other word or character.